# Google Workspace User EMail Access

Tags: g-suite

Google Workspace Admin trying to access user's email account who is no longer with the company is running into Google security blocking access and requiring text authentication. The real problem is that the phone number belongs to the user who is no longer with the company.

Q1) What's the best ways to get around this? I have spent good 30 min on this topic and I am out of ideas.

Q2) Is there a ways to replace the phone number linked to user's account with Admin's number?

Q3) Is there a ways to unflag the phone number when admin's number is flagged and Google refuses to authenticate to the number? Admin is running out of phone numbers to receive the Google authentication code. :(

-Oktokie

Comment: My Google Suite admin gives me the ability to turn off 2FA for a user. If you don't have it, I'd call Google support.

Comment: Currently MFA has been turned off for the entire domain. Text message authentication Admin is running into is when Google bot thinks suspicious activity is going on and has flagged the account and Admin's phone number. Some user's account has their phone number tagged hard to the account and refuses send authentication text message elsewhere. There must be something can be done, because if Admin can't get control of the user's account then who can? Thanks.
-Oktokie

Answer (score 0):

Doh! Just discovered that you can update each user's security by clicking on the user from the directory and updating the recovery phone information.
-Paul

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).